# Find/sed: How can I recursively search/replace a string in files but only for lines that match a particular regexp

Tags: regex, bash, sed, find

I'm aware that the following command can be used to recursively replace all instances of a particular string with another:

find /path/to/files -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/oldstring/newstring/g'

However, I need to do this only for lines that start with a particular string ("matchstr").

For example, if a file contained the following lines:

```
This line containing oldstring should remain untouched
matchstr sometext oldstring somethingelse
```

I want to have this as output:

```
This line containing oldstring should remain untouched
matchstr sometext newstring somethingelse
```

Any suggestions as to how I could proceed would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do:

```
sed -i '/^matchstr/{s/oldstring/newstring/g}'
```

ie

```
find /path/to/files -type f -print0 | \
  xargs -0 sed -i '/^matchstr/{s/oldstring/newstring/g}'
```

The first `/^matchstr/` looks for lines matching that regex, and for those lines the `s/old/new/g` is performed.

Comment: Actually neither brackets nor whitespace is necessary — you can just use `sed -i '/^matchstr/s/oldstring/newstring/g'`.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this easily using sed:

```
sed -e '/^matchstr/ s/oldstring/newstring/g' inputfile
```

`/^matchstr/` acts as a condition; it makes it execute the following block only if the regex matches. In this case we're looking for `matchstr` at the beginning of the line.