# How do I recursively search and replace directory paths in terminal Mac?

Tags: macos, replace, sed, terminal, find

I've looked at the following other threads which recommend a particular 'sed' command:

https://superuser.com/questions/428493/how-can-i-do-a-recursive-find-and-replace-from-the-command-line

[Find/sed: How can I recursively search/replace a string in files but only for lines that match a particular regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577204/find-sed-how-can-i-recursively-search-replace-a-string-in-files-but-only-for-li)

[Recursive search and replace in text files on Mac and Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704020/recursive-search-and-replace-on-mac-and-linux)

```
perl -pi -w -e 's/SEARCH_FOR/REPLACE_WITH/g;' *.txt
```

And

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec sed -i '' s/this/that/ {} +
```

I am trying to replace this sample below that occurs in multiple files in the directory:

> ```
> <script src="http://localhost/massignition/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen/js/html5.js"></script>
> ```

with the following (substituting localhost/massignition with www.site.com)

I type the following:

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec sed -i '' s%localhost/massignition%www.site.com%/ {} +
```

But nothing changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove / which is present in before curly braces in your command, that is

find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec sed -i '' s%localhost/massignition%www.site.com% {} +

instead of

find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec sed -i '' s%localhost/massignition%www.site.com%/ {} +

Comment: Yes, I made that adjustments after posting but wasn't sure if it was working but looks like it does, thanks.